# Continuously resizing windows in Vim

Tags: vim, window

I know I can use `CTRL-w -`/`CTRL-w +` to Incrementally decrease/increase the windows. However, I would like to do exactly the same thing continuously. e.g. without having to click everytime `CTRL-w` and then `Shift =` (to get `+`) (I know I have do something like `CTRL-w 5+` but I would like incremental, continous increase).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are the mappings I use myself. Works continuously by holding the keys:

```
" Window resize via Alt + Shift + arrows
map <A-S-Left> <C-W>>
map <A-S-Right> <C-W><
map <A-S-Up> <C-W>+
map <A-S-Down> <C-W>-
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on using the keyboard, Vim windows can be resized with the mouse. In terminal Vim you may need to `:set mouse=a` first.